# std::reference_wrapper on MS Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, reference-wrapper

I try to compile some code which is very similar to:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class A{
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<const A>> stringToRef;
  A a;
  const A& b = a;
  stringToRef.insert(std::make_pair("Test", b));
  return 0;
}
```

But can't figure out, why it's not compiling. I'm pretty sure, that the same code compiled fine on MS Visual Studio 2012 - but on Visual Studio 2013, it reports the following compilation error:

```
error C2280: std::reference_wrapper<const A>::reference_wrapper(_Ty &&): attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I tried to add copy, move, assignment operators to my class - but couldn't get rid of this error. How can I find out exactly, which deleted function this error refers to?

Comment: `std::make_pair("Test", b)` makes a pair containing a copy of `b`, not `b` itself.

Comment: C++11 is still C++, so please retain the tag. I've made this correction on your questions so far. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to store a `std::reference_wrapper<const A>`, so you can use `[std::cref][1]` to get that directly from `a`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

class A{
};

int main(int argc, char* argv []){
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<const A>> stringToRef;
  A a;
  stringToRef.insert(std::make_pair("Test", std::cref(a)));
  return 0;
}
```

This works with [GCC/Clang+libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d865d828656eefa), [Clang+libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e73c9203994d223e), and MSVS 2013 (tested locally).